# React Typescript cancel executing interruption on typescript error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm converting a project from jsx to tsx files.
on this project, I receive objects from server and console.log() them to see the types of each object, then writing for them types definitions in typescript.

the problem is that typescript interrupting the execution before I get to fetch these objects.

how do I disable the code execution interruption but still get errors(on ts terminal or on web console)?

Comment: Not sure I follow, but can you use an _explicit_ `any`?

Comment: @Nick Not sure what you mean by explicit `any`

Comment: anyone? someone must know how to do this

Comment: Explicitly typing `any` means in your function you type it as `(parameter: any) => `, for example

Comment: you probably did not understand what I asked. this is not related to a specific error. I want the UI to keep running even if there are typescript errors.

Comment: Typescript is a compiled language. If it can’t compile, it won’t run. That’s actually a feature of the language! If you want it to run, write compliant typescript. Use loose typing if you need to and then tighten it up when you understand the structure better.

Comment: not agree. you can run typescript in codesandbox for example and even when there are typescript errors the UI keeps running but you get the logging of the error.
as you said it's typescript is not a runtime language so there is no reason to stop the running of the application when there is a compilation error (it's not like C when the actual compiled code is used to run the application. typescript only checks that your code fits to the types you declared and the compiled code can run anyway.)